# WSO2 Developer Studio doesn't show ESB flows

Tags: wso2, wso2-integration-studio

Having WSO2 Developer Studio (Eclipse Mars + ESB 5.0.0 Tooling + BPS 3.6.0 Tooling) it seems to be working nicely, but after certain time (actions ? update?) the ESB sequence or proxy diagrams are not shown with exception.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.gmf.esb.diagram.part.EsbDiagramEditor.configureGraphicalViewer(EsbDiagramEditor.java:339)
    at org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.diagram.ui.parts.DiagramEditor.createGraphicalViewer(DiagramEditor.java:806)
    at org.eclipse.gef.ui.parts.GraphicalEditor.createPartControl(GraphicalEditor.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.diagram.ui.parts.DiagramEditor.createPartControl(DiagramEditor.java:1580)
    at org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.diagram.ui.parts.DiagramEditorWithFlyOutPalette.createPartControl(DiagramEditorWithFlyOutPalette.java:328)
    at org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.diagram.ui.resources.editor.parts.DiagramDocumentEditor.createPartControl(DiagramDocumentEditor.java:1514)
    at org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart.addPage(MultiPageEditorPart.java:244)
    at org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.gmf.esb.diagram.part.EsbMultiPageEditor.createPage0(EsbMultiPageEditor.java:287)
    at org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.gmf.esb.diagram.part.EsbMultiPageEditor.createPages(EsbMultiPageEditor.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart.createPartControl(MultiPageEditorPart.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.createPartControl(CompatibilityPart.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityEditor.createPartControl(CompatibilityEditor.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.create(CompatibilityPart.java:341)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:898)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:879)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:121)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:264)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ContributedPartRenderer.createWidget(ContributedPartRenderer.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createWidget(PartRenderingEngine.java:971)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:640)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:746)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$0(PartRenderingEngine.java:717)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:711)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:695)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl$1.handleEvent(PartServiceImpl.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler$1.run(UIEventHandler.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.syncExec(Synchronizer.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer.syncExec(UISynchronizer.java:145)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.syncExec(Display.java:4761)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application$1.syncExec(E4Application.java:211)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler.handleEvent(UIEventHandler.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerWrapper.handleEvent(EventHandlerWrapper.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.dispatchEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.sendEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventComponent.sendEvent(EventComponent.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.EventBroker.send(EventBroker.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.UIEventPublisher.notifyChanged(UIEventPublisher.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.emf.common.notify.impl.BasicNotifierImpl.eNotify(BasicNotifierImpl.java:374)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.impl.ElementContainerImpl.setSelectedElement(ElementContainerImpl.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.showElementInWindow(ModelServiceImpl.java:572)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.bringToTop(ModelServiceImpl.java:536)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.delegateBringToTop(PartServiceImpl.java:724)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.bringToTop(PartServiceImpl.java:396)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.showPart(PartServiceImpl.java:1166)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3252)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$25(WorkbenchPage.java:3167)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$10.run(WorkbenchPage.java:3149)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3144)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3108)
    at org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.gmf.esb.diagram.custom.utils.GraphicalEditorStartupUtils.editorOpen(GraphicalEditorStartupUtils.java:97)
    at org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.gmf.esb.diagram.custom.utils.GraphicalEditorStartupUtils.editorOpen(GraphicalEditorStartupUtils.java:44)
    at org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.artifact.proxyservice.ui.wizard.ProxyServiceProjectCreationWizard.openEditor(ProxyServiceProjectCreationWizard.java:300)
    at org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.artifact.proxyservice.ui.wizard.ProxyServiceProjectCreationWizard.performFinish(ProxyServiceProjectCreationWizard.java:159)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.finishPressed(WizardDialog.java:799)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.buttonPressed(WizardDialog.java:429)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog$2.widgetSelected(Dialog.java:619)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4362)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1113)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4180)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3769)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:827)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:803)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.wizards.WizardShortcutAction.run(WizardShortcutAction.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:595)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:511)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:420)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4362)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1113)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4180)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3769)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1018)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:694)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:669)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1515)
```

Even reinstalling the tool and plugins doesn't help, it looks like something with the project settings. Unfortunately I am only an eclipse user and I don't know what information could I provider to get any help.

Recreating projects would be troublesome as the development is certain stadium. However - the DEV studio can be still used for BPS (BPEL) and building the composite apps.

Answer (score 1):

I've also got this same error using ***Red Hat JBoss Developer Studio*** when I try to open any WSO2 project diagram in ***JBoss* *perspective***.

I guess in the others eclipse distributions could happen the same issue, but the solution could be the same.

[image]

[image]

---

In my case I've just solved this way

1. Closing all WSO2 diagrams files.
2. Changing the perspective to **Java EE pespective** or **Java perspective**. Furthermore, I recommend the Java EE perspective to work with WSO2.

[image]

3. Then reopen the respectives WSO2 diagrams files.

[image]

---

Lastly to be sure to update WSO2 Developer Studio packages. This can be done either in ***Developer Studio*** or **Check for Updates** menu.

[image]

[image]